# What should we do with humour in questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Here an example of question I revised:
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9127

Personally I thought it was confusing because of all the necessary information in it. My edit was accepted hence my question:

When a question contains humoristic content unrelated to the meaning of the question should we remove this content? Is it acceptable to do so even if it deeply changes the author and question's writing style?

Comment: Does it harm? Do you have an example?

Comment: It harms when it makes the questions confusing (see my example) or is useless and so make the readers focusing on something else than the real purpose of the question.

Comment: I would not write a general rule. See this [related question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/is-this-rejected-edit-in-line-with-se-goals) and my own answer, as well as Michael comment on it.

Comment: I'm sure that authur is finishing assembling an army of 300 Gandalf-1000 retrofits with a Xiphos and an Apsis, the only problem left is where to put them any idea? Lol

Comment: See also http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/flavor-in-questions.